# Web scraping across multiple pages using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape information about renewable energy manufacturers, suppliers and companies in Europe on the following website: [https://www.energy-xprt.com/renewable-energy/companies/location-europe/](https://stackoverflow.com).

The first step is to collect urls of each company in the list but when I run a loop to scrape across pages I obtain links of the companies from the first page. My code looks like

```
link <- paste0('https://www.energy-xprt.com/renewable-energy/companies/location-europe/page-',1:78)  
result <- lapply(link, function(x) x %>% 
                   read_html %>% html_nodes("[class='h2 mb-0']") %>% html_elements('a') %>% html_attr('href')
                 ) %>% unlist() %>% unique()
```

I expect to obtain a vector that contains urls of companies from all 78 pages

Comment: Interesting.  Seems that `rvest` always gets redirected back to the first page. And it still behaves the same way when switching to `rvest::session()`  or using cookies and  other headers from a browser session with `httr2` . Are you perhaps open to solutions that are not rvest-based?

Comment: Yes, sure. The main objective is to collect the above mentioned urls. The method doesn't matter

Comment: All of those are being redirected to the same page (for me). Try `res <- httr::GET(link[1]); sapply(res$all_headers, \`[[\`, "status")` and note that the first two HTTP requests return a status of [HTTP 301](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/301), a "moved permanently" redirection to `"https://energy-xprt.com/renewable-energy/companies"` and then `"https://www.energy-xprt.com/renewable-energy/companies"`, respectively. if you are able to see differently in a browser, perhaps it's because you are authenticated or they are using other filters (geoip, useragent, referrer).

Comment: This is true when using `httr::GET` as well as `rvest::session(link[1])`. It occurred in my firefox browser, suggesting (to me) that it is not useragent (alone). I tried adding `httr::add_headers(referrer="https://www.energy-xprt.com")`, and it was also redirected, so the referrer (alone) is also not it. Bottom line, your problem is not with your code, it's with your assumption that the data is from the page you requested.

Comment: So John, if you're able to demonstrate that you get something from _that URL_ without a redirect (recognize `$all_headers`, not just `$headers`, they are different), please post how you're able to accomplish that.

Comment: It seems to me that my requests are also redirected. So, I'm in search of the method that could be able to circumvent redirection to the first page

Answer (score 0):

Seems that static (or just curl-based?) tools like `rvest` and `httr` / `httr2` are always redirected to the same page, so let's try to get that content through Chrome / `chromote`. But instead of pointing `chromote` to a list of URLs (would not work anyway, redirects back to `https://www.energy-xprt.com/renewable-energy/companies` ) or triggering `click()` methods, we can use JavaScript `fetch()` in `chromote` Runtime, pull raw text response from `chromote` and process it in R with `rvest`. This way Chrome does not need to render those pages nor download linked resources, while request headers (incl. session cookies ) are all nicely set and match our browser session.

```r
library(chromote)
library(rvest)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
library(stringr)

b <- ChromoteSession$new()
{
  b$Page$navigate("https://www.energy-xprt.com/renewable-energy/companies/location-europe")
  b$Page$loadEventFired()
} 
#> $timestamp
#> [1] 163274

# instead of navigating through pages, we'll just fetch page content with js and return it as text;
# create a small helper function in js runtime to make following calls bit more compact; 
# function is asynchronous and returns a Promise, but that's fine
b$Runtime$evaluate("function fetch_text(url) {return fetch(url).then(response => response.text())}")
#> $result
#> $result$type
#> [1] "undefined"

# we'll call fetch_text(..) for all pages, awaitPromise = TRUE awaits unitl js Promise gets resolved
# map() output will be a named list (page-1, page-2, ...) of extracted urls,
# enframe creates a nested tibble (78×2) which we'll unnest to a long 1542×2 tibble
url_df <- str_c("page-", 1:78) |>
  set_names() |>
  map(\(page) str_glue("fetch_text('https://www.energy-xprt.com/renewable-energy/companies/location-europe/{page}')")) |>
  map(\(js_call) b$Runtime$evaluate(js_call, awaitPromise = TRUE)$result$value |>
        read_html() |>
        html_elements("h2[class='h2 mb-0'] > a") |> 
        html_attr('href')
      ) |>
  enframe(name = "page", value = "url") |>
  unnest_longer(url)
```

Results:

```r
url_df
#> # A tibble: 1,542 × 2
#>    page   url                                                                   
#>    <chr>  <chr>                                                                 
#>  1 page-1 https://www.energy-xprt.com/companies/zygo-corporation-ametek-inc-101…
#>  2 page-1 https://www.energy-xprt.com/companies/weda-ab-10468                   
#>  3 page-1 https://www.energy-xprt.com/companies/lindner-recyclingtech-gmbh-3552 
#>  4 page-1 https://www.energy-xprt.com/companies/real-tech-inc-37526             
#>  5 page-1 https://www.energy-xprt.com/companies/advanced-energy-industries-inc-…
#>  6 page-1 https://www.energy-xprt.com/companies/solar-turbines-incorporated-286…
#>  7 page-1 https://www.energy-xprt.com/companies/envitec-biogas-ag-29450         
#>  8 page-1 https://www.energy-xprt.com/companies/hrs-heat-exchangers-ltd-19747   
#>  9 page-1 https://www.energy-xprt.com/companies/delta-t-devices-ltd-775         
#> 10 page-1 https://www.energy-xprt.com/companies/entech-renewable-energy-solutio…
#> # ℹ 1,532 more rows

tail(url_df)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 2
#>   page    url                                                                  
#>   <chr>   <chr>                                                                
#> 1 page-77 https://www.energy-xprt.com/companies/fuel-tech-inc-35874            
#> 2 page-77 https://www.energy-xprt.com/companies/purenviro-as-40264             
#> 3 page-77 https://www.energy-xprt.com/companies/kt-kinetics-technology-spa-9236
#> 4 page-77 https://www.energy-xprt.com/companies/biogastechnik-sued-gmbh-147066 
#> 5 page-78 https://www.energy-xprt.com/companies/bmh-technology-oy-19660        
#> 6 page-78 https://www.energy-xprt.com/companies/feedwater-ltd-41643

# 3 first urls from every page to make sure we are not running in circles
url_df |> 
  slice_head(n = 3, by = page)
#> # A tibble: 233 × 2
#>    page   url                                                                   
#>    <chr>  <chr>                                                                 
#>  1 page-1 https://www.energy-xprt.com/companies/zygo-corporation-ametek-inc-101…
#>  2 page-1 https://www.energy-xprt.com/companies/weda-ab-10468                   
#>  3 page-1 https://www.energy-xprt.com/companies/lindner-recyclingtech-gmbh-3552 
#>  4 page-2 https://www.energy-xprt.com/companies/zeeco-inc-45526                 
#>  5 page-2 https://www.energy-xprt.com/companies/flammatec-spol-s-ro-130539      
#>  6 page-2 https://www.energy-xprt.com/companies/electria-wind-134493            
#>  7 page-3 https://www.energy-xprt.com/companies/trasfeco-srl-48302              
#>  8 page-3 https://www.energy-xprt.com/companies/enertec-kraftwerke-gmbh-35958   
#>  9 page-3 https://www.energy-xprt.com/companies/n-bio-gmbh-36559                
#> 10 page-4 https://www.energy-xprt.com/companies/neste-27323                     
#> # ℹ 223 more rows

# number of urls collected from each page
url_df |> 
  count(page)
#> # A tibble: 78 × 2
#>    page        n
#>    <chr>   <int>
#>  1 page-1     20
#>  2 page-10    20
#>  3 page-11    20
#>  4 page-12    20
#>  5 page-13    20
#>  6 page-14    20
#>  7 page-15    20
#>  8 page-16    20
#>  9 page-17    20
#> 10 page-18    20
#> # ℹ 68 more rows
```

Note that there are still some issues; for me it currently returns 1089 unique values (site reports 1542 matches), order does not match desktop browser session (perhaps a side effect of `fetch()`-based approach... ) and occasionally that site just behaves oddly. For example *page-3* in a browser was broken for me at some point -- other pagination pages worked fine but this one triggered re-direction to `https://www.energy-xprt.com/renewable-energy/companies`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I repeated the algorithm three times and got 1542 unique urls